# Concurrency in MySQL Innodb Transactions when executing 2 seperated queries

Tags: python, mysql

```
My Schema

Table Articles
id -> AUTO_INCREMENT
article_name -> STRING
hash_id -> STRING
```

this is my code, Python

```
cursor.execute("Insert into articles(id,article_name) values (NULL,'Harry Potter')")

id = cursor.lastrowid # Gets the AUTO_INCRENT value

hash_id = hash_id_function(id) # converts INT to Non-Sequential eg. '112' -> '23jk32j'

cursor.execute("UPDATE Articles set hash_id='23jk32j' where id='112'")
```

Whenever a READ occurs, I want the ROW to contain the hashid (Above 2 Queries must have executed fully)

How can i achieve this with Transactions, Considering that MySQL(Innodb) has to wait for my pythonic `hash_id_function` to execute?

Comment: what is your hash id function actually doing? could you not "export" this to mysql itself, so that you can use a trigger to automatically set hash_id

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be using triggers. To implement this, you would either have to translate your `hash_id_function()` as mysql function, or you use one of the build-in function from mysql.

You install the trigger once by executing one of the sample queries below and in future inserts it will be executed automatically.

This sample trigger uses `SHA2()` to build the hash, you could use `MD5()`:

```
delimiter //
drop trigger if exists tg_bi_articles //

create trigger tg_bi_articles before insert on articles
for each row begin
  set new.hash_id = (
    SELECT SHA2(AUTO_INCREMENT,0) 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME='articles' 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE());
end;
//

delimiter ;
```

If you don't need such a secure hash, you could just take the first few chars from the hash:

```
delimiter //
drop trigger if exists tg_bi_articles //

create trigger tg_bi_articles before insert on articles
for each row begin
  set new.hash_id = (
    SELECT LEFT(MD5(AUTO_INCREMENT),5) 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME='articles' 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE());
end;
//

delimiter ;
```

If you need a hash that is able to be decrypted then you can use AES_ENCRYPT

```
delimiter //
drop trigger if exists tg_bi_articles //

create trigger tg_bi_articles before insert on articles
for each row begin
  set new.hash_id = (
    SELECT AES_ENCRYPT(AUTO_INCREMENT,UNHEX('FA32C2E389AB50213F530C0CA1A390C3')) 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME='articles' 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE());
end;
//

delimiter ;
```

Last option would be translating your function as SQL function and adding that to the trigger, but what ever you do ***triggers do the magic for you*** :) Because now when you do following insert

```
cursor.execute("Insert into articles(id,article_name) values (NULL,'Harry Potter')")
```

then this is what you will find in database (when using second sample trigger):

```
( 3, 'Harry Potter', 'eccbc' )
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The Key is using MySQL Transactions in Connector/Python

```
cnx.autocommit = False # Sets Autocommit to False, 

cursor.execute(Insert_Query) 
id = cursor.lastrowid; #Get Last Autoincrement value

hash_id = hash_id_function(id)
cursor.execute("UPDATE Table set hash_id=...")# Run the Update Query

cnx.commit() # Commit your changes, 

except ValueError as err:
 cnx.rollback() # If something happens Rollback (UNDO the changes)
```

This will ensure integrity throughout the tables

Learn more on [Transactions](http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-transactions-php-emulation/) in MySQL